# Can't ping subnet behind OpenVPN server

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, iptables, ping

Here is my infrastructure:

```
dns of mydomain.com:
  vpn A 90.90.90.1
  vpn A 90.90.90.2

client vpn config:
  client
  dev tun
  proto udp
  nobind
  remote vpn.mydomain.com 1394

server1
  net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
  iptables:
    FORWARD defaults to ACCEPT
  vpn config:
    dev tun
    topology subnet
    port 1394
    proto udp
    server 10.10.1.0 255.255.255.0
    push "route 10.90.90.0 255.255.255.0"
  interfaces:
    ifpub: 90.90.90.1/24
    ifpriv: 10.90.90.1/24
    ifvpn: 10.10.1.1/24
  routes:
    10.10.1.0/24 src 10.10.1.1 dev ifvpn
    10.10.2.0/24 via 10.90.90.2 dev ifpriv

server2
  net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
  iptables:
    FORWARD defaults to ACCEPT
  vpn config:
    dev tun
    topology subnet
    port 1394
    proto udp
    server 10.10.2.0 255.255.255.0
    push "route 10.90.90.0 255.255.255.0"
  interfaces:
    ifpub: 90.90.90.2/24
    ifpriv: 10.90.90.2/24
    ifvpn: 10.10.2.1/24
  routes:
    10.10.1.0/24 via 10.90.90.1 dev ifpriv
    10.10.2.0/24 src 10.10.2.1 dev ifvpn
```

The problem is that from my client I can ping the OpenVPN server I'm connected to, but not the other server in the 10.90.90.0/24 subnet.

`tcpdump` shows that the ICMP request goes from `ifvpn` to `ifpriv` on the same server but then the ICMP request packet never go further.

Adding logging to iptables also show me that the ICMP request packet goes to the POSTROUTING state without being dropped but then the packet never made it to its destination, and I don't know what happen here, I'm out of solutions.

I known I can masquerade my packets, but I don't want to because it's not recommanded (https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/NatHack), or it will be my very very last solution.

Comment: I tried the masquerade hack and it works. `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.10.1.0/24 -o ifpriv -j MASQUERADE` on the server 1 for example and I can now ping the server 2 private ip from my client.
But as described in the NatHack page `The authorities would see all the telephone calls as coming from you. It would be better if everyone got their own phone, so the calls could be routed directly.`. So the problem is still here...

Comment: IIRC OpenVPN needs some special configuration on top of routing to access a complete subnet. I'll see if I can find the details.

Comment: I believe you need to allow iptables INPUT on server2 for the ping to reach server2.

Comment: I've tested to add PREROUTING log on server2 but see nothing coming. I've assumed that PREROUTING is the first chain the packet would enter as described in this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wdkF.png ?

Comment: Dug it up: You need [iroute](https://backreference.org/2009/11/15/openvpn-and-iroute/) on some topologies, but that doesn't seem to apply here. If I understand you correctly, the `ifpriv` interfaces on both servers are connected by LAN, and you see an outgoing packet on `ifpriv` on server 1, but it never enteres `ifpriv` on server 2, is that correct? Stupid question: Can you ping server 2 from server 1 directly?

Comment: Yes it's exactly that. And yes I can ping server2 from server1. From what I understand, `iroute` is useful when you want your to connect to the client LAN, not the server LAN.

Answer (score 0):

If the remote server "exposes a subnet," you must have a `ccd` directory containing files with `iroute` directives, as carefully described in the OpenVPN documentation.  You must also have `route` directives pushed to the clients.

When everything is working correctly:

- The client sends the ping.
- The client's OS has a routing-command which sends this traffic to the local OpenVPN server.
- The `ccd` information tells OpenVPN *to which connected remote* to send the traffic for delivery.
- The traffic emerges at this remote and proceeds to its destination.
- For the return trip, the remote system must *also* have an operating-system route which will send the traffic back to *its* OpenVPN server.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will try that. Where is the documentation you were describing? I was using this one: https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#scope